# Cook-Levin Theorem implies a transformation from witnesses to witnesses

Tags: cook-levin

The book by Wigderson includes this quote on page 39, following the statement of the Cook-Levin theorem that $SAT$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete:

> The proof of this theorem (namely, the construction of the reduction
> algorithm $f$ ) gives an extra bonus that turns out to be extremely
> useful: It maps witnesses to witnesses. More precisely, for any
> witness $y$ certifying that $z \in C$ (via some verifier $VC$ ), the same
> reduction $f$ converts the witness $y$ to a Boolean assignment of the
> variables of the formula $f(z)$ that satisfy it. In other words, this
> reduction translates not only between the decision problems, but also
> between the associated search problems.

The Arora-Barak book makes a similar remark, on page 50 under "More Thoughts on the Cook-Levin Theorem":

> The reduction $f$ from an $\mathsf{NP}$-language $L$ to $SAT$ presented in Lemma 2.11
> not only satisfied that $x \in L \iff f(x) \in SAT$ but actually the proof
> yields an efficient way to transform a certificate for $x$ to a
> satisfying assignment for $f(x)$ and vice versa. We call a reduction
> with this property a Levin reduction. One can also modify the proof
> slightly (see Exercise 2.13) so that it actually supplies us with a
> one-to-one and onto map between the set of certificates for $x$ and the
> set of satisfying assignments for $f(x)$, implying that they are of the
> same size.

There are other references to this fact of the Cook-Levin theorem. Recall that the proof of the Cook-Levin theorem takes a computation history of a Turing machine, a polytime verifier, and produces a polysized CNF formula which is satisfiable if and only if the verifier accepted.

I do not see how the Cook-Levin theorem implies this transformation from witnesses to witnesses, as it does from problems to problems. I would appreciate any directions or pointers, I feel like I may be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This essentially stems from the fact that satisfying assignments of the produced formula encode accepting computation paths of the nondeterministic TM for the problem that we started with. As may assume that this NTM works by first "guessing" a certificate nondeterministically and then verifying it using a deterministic procedure, which allows us to "read off" the original certificate from a satisfying assignment.